# Unable to get one object from the array in JSON

Tags: swift

I'm building a Currency Converter App and I've faced a problem. I want to write a full name of the currency under the Picker, but I can't do it regularly. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
@State var pickerSelection1: Int = 0
Picker("", selection: $pickerSelection1) {
            ForEach(0..<self.api.currencyCode1.count) {
                let currency = api.currencyCode1[$0]
                Text(currency)
                }
            }
        .id(UUID())
        .labelsHidden()
        .padding()
Text(api.txt[pickerSelection1])// Bug is here
```

Instead of showing my full name it's writing this:

```
Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
2021-11-08 13:31:37.166704+0200 CurrencyConverter[3686:109902] Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range
```

How can I fix it?
I'm not attaching JSON file, because, as I get it, It's not the main problem

Comment: You're using two different arrays. 'currencyCode1' seems to be one array, and 'txt' seems to be another one. Are you sure they're always going to have the same amount of elements in them?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I didn’t see the last line until the edit and the comment above from @JeffCournoyer. Given that I wonder if you have a bad design in your `api` type, do you have your data spread out over several arrays instead of using a single array with a custom type? Or what is the correlation between the two arrays?